# Building Composite Apps Documentation "Login Required"

Tags: documentation

Tried to find some articles on Composite apps and followed this link,

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/SFDC:Archived_Intro_to_Force.com:_Building_Composite_Apps

and curiously ended on this page below.

[image: Login Required]

The document was updated back to 1969. What's going on here?

Comment: Where did you *find* that link? Also the time stamp is probably just a permissions issue.

Comment: @AdrianLarson, the link is from the Google search results. Thanks

Comment: Notice that the link text begins with `SFDC:Archived`. Clearly the documentation team no longer wants this resource to be public.